# Ударение в фамилии Понятовский

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия, фамилии

На какой слог ударение в фамилии Понятовский?

Answer (score 0):

На О.
Фамилия польского происхождения, Понятовские - польский княжеский род, ударение в польском всегда на предпоследний слог. Так что если речь идёт о ком-то из известных носителей фамилии (маршале Наполеона, например, Юзефе-Антонии, или последнем польском короле СтанИславе-Августе), то только так.

Comment: Понятовские - предпоследний слог буква И)

Answer (score 0):

Простите, не совсем понял про Юзефа со СтанИславом, но, в принципе, ответ верен с маленьким дополнением: ударение падает на последнюю гласную перед суффиксом. Как то: ПендерЕцкий, ЗагОрский, РокоссОвский, КовАльский, МицкЕвич и пр. и соответственно фамилии княжеских родов так же произносятся, как и менее именитых...

Comment: Простите, но про суффикс - Ваши фантазии. **Всегда** - на предпоследний слог. Есть суффикс, нет  ли, есть ли окончания - нет ли. Я не могу сказать, что знаю польский, но немного польскую речь понимаю - и даже читаю (как и на многих славянских). Но ни о каких исключениях не слышал. 

>Ударение в польском языке связанное: оно почти всегда ставится на предпоследний слог. Исключения составляют некоторые заимствования и формы глагола в сослагательном наклонении.  

Вики.

Comment: Никак не могу понять, в чем разница двух ответов. Последняя гласная перед суффиксом - это предпоследняя в целом слове.

Comment: Про Юзефа и СтинИслава ничего понимать не надо. Если речь идет об известных носителях фамилии, в чяисле коих были и упомянутые, то ударение на предпоследний слог.  
Если не о них, а о ком-то из русских, например, носителей то фамилия подвергнуться русскому влиянию и ударение сместиться.

Comment: >Никак не могу понять, в чем разница двух ответов. Последняя гласная перед суффиксом - это предпоследняя в целом слове.    

А вы это попродуйте поляку объянить. Который пОляк. Или тому же СтанИславу ПонятОвскому. Который в дательном - "СтанислАву ПонятовскЕму".  

Единственное, что может иметь некоторое отношение к суффиксу - это глагол. В формах прошедшего времени и сослагательного наклонения ударение действительно падает на последний слог перед суффиксом, т.е. на третий или четвертый с конца: czyt**a**liśmy (мы читали)
obеjrz**a**łybyśmy (мы бы осмотрели). Но это - глагол!

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, ударение в фамилии - вещь в себе. Взять хотя бы "русскую фамилию в первом десятке" - Иванов. Лично знаю (родственные отношения) носителей всех трёх вариантов: "Ивановы, Ив"ановы и Иван"овы.

Точно так же, к примеру, в классе у дочери: фамилия Кораблев, без Ё, ударение на последний слог. Вот так.